# Python dictionary in Jinja

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

I'm getting a weird problem in jinja. It seems simple but i'm getting it right. In a jinja template with `{{tag["tag"] }}` it is echoing `{u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'tourism'}` but when I am trying to get the value with `{{tag["tag"]["value"] }}`, I am getting the error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'tag'` from the following strace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vocabularies.py", line 16, in <module>
    table_html = ontology_table.render(fields=["title","domain","tags","expressivity"],rows=table_data["data"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.3-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.3-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<template>", line 42, in top-level template code
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.3-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 378, in getitem
    return obj[argument]
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'tag'
```

In fact i'm loading a json string which contains a tags object like

```
{"tags": [{"tagObj": {"type": "uri", "value": "http://ci.emse.fr/opensensingcity/ns/sca/tourism"}, "tag": {"type": "literal", "value": "tourism"}}]}
```

and the jinja code below is failing with the stacktrace i provided:

```
{% for tag in row["tags"]%}
    <span class="label label-info">{{tag["tag"]["value"] }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can you please paste code ?

Comment: i've pasted the code as well as dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tag = {"tags": [{"tagObj": {"type": "uri", "value": "http://ci.emse.fr/opensensingcity/ns/sca/tourism"}, "tag": {"type": "literal", "value": "tourism"}}]}
```

you can get value using `tag['tags'][0]['tag']['value']`
and your out put will be `'tourism'` in this way.

Comment: are you sure {{tag["tag"] }} gives you output ? I think it is {{tags["tag"] }},if  it is then try {{tags["tag"]["value"] }}

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code -

```
{% for key, value in dict.iteritems() %}
            {{ key }}
            {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: for the json I posted, i'm getting this: tagObj-{u'type': u'uri', u'value': u'http://ci.emse.fr/opensensingcity/ns/sca/tourism'} tag-{u'type': u'literal', u'value': u'tourism'}